# Why does opendir() work for one string but not another?

Tags: c, stdin

I would like to open a directory using `opendir` but am seeing something unexpected. `opendir` works for the string returned from `getcwd` but not the string from my helper function `read_cwd`, even though the strings appear to be equal.

If I print the strings, both print `/Users/gwg/x`, which is the current working directory.

Here is my code:

```
char real_cwd[255];
getcwd(real_cwd, sizeof(real_cwd));

/* This reads a virtual working directory from a file */
char virt_cwd[255];
read_cwd(virt_cwd);

/* This prints "1" */
printf("%d\n", strcmp(real_cwd, virt_cwd) != 0);

/* This works for real_cwd but not virt_cwd */
DIR *d = opendir(/* real_cwd | virt_cwd */);
```

Here is the code for `read_cwd`:

```
char *read_cwd(char *cwd_buff)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(X_PATH_FILE, "r");
    fgets(cwd_buff, 80, f);
    printf("Read cwd %s\n", cwd_buff);
    fclose(f);
    return cwd_buff;
}
```

Comment: If `strcmp(real_cwd, virt_cwd) != 0` then the strings are *not* equal

Comment: Ah. It returns `0` if they *are* equal? Why do they look the same?

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of the string?  fgets will preserve it, so you have to manually remove it.

Comment: @gwg Yes, 0 means the strings *are* equal.  -1 means the first string is ordered first, and 1 means the second string is ordered first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `fgets` includes the final newline in the buffer — so the second string is actually `"/Users/gwg/x\n"`.

The simplest (but not necessarily the cleanest) way to solve this issue is to overwrite the newline with a `'\0'`: add the following at the end of the function `read_cwd`:

```
n = strlen(cwd_buff);
if(n > 0 && cwd_buff[n - 1] == '\n')
    cwd_buff[n - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: [`strlen()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27729970/2410359) (like this answer) and [`strchr()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2693826/2410359), IMO, are the 2 best clean ways to remove `'\n'` after `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` includes the newline.

> Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character. — http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets

---

You should trim the white space on both ends of the string when reading input like this.

Answer (score 1):

From the `fgets` man page:

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
>   stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.**
>   A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in
>   the buffer.

You need to remove the newline character from the string you are reading in.